# Easy Admin 3 Sort by date returns: create_date has no field or association named create_date

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

I'm trying to sort a field either by asc or desc date.

When i add the date field to my backend like so

```
DateTimeField::new('create_date', 'Create Date')->setSortable(true),
```

It works and it shows, but when i try to sort it i get the following error

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 'create_date ': Error: Class App\\Entity\\MyEntitiy has no field or association named create_date File:/home/wwwroot/htdocs/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php Line: 63
```

Does anyone know why or how this happens ?

Thank you

EDIT: here is the field in MyEntity

```
   /**
     * @var \DateTime|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="create_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createDate;


 /**
 * Returns the CreateDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime|null
 */
public function getCreateDate(): ?\DateTime
{
    return $this->createDate;
}


/**
 * Sets the CreateDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime|null $createDate
 * @return void
 */
public function setCreateDate(?\DateTime $createDate)
{
    $this->createDate = $createDate;
}
```

Comment: Well.. can we see your entity and especially your property "create_date" ? that seem to not exist ?

Comment: Yeah that's the catch. It does. I will share it ofc :D

Comment: Please see the post now, i added it.

Comment: @DylanKas The weird behavior is that i see all the dates in the list, just when i click to sort them i get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not respecting the proper spelling for your property.

In your entity, the field is called `createDate` so you should use the same name when configuring your crud.

In your case :

```
DateTimeField::new('createDate', 'Create Date')->setSortable(true),
```